# Send class object data to different class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I need help. I created a object in one class and cannot pass the info to a different class. 
This is the class I'm trying to make an object with

```
class BankAccount():
    def __init__(self, name, acct):
        self.full_name = name
        self.acctNum = acct
        self.balance = 0

    def withdraw(self, w):
        self.balance = self.balance - w
        w = float(w)
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, d):
        self.balance = self.balance + d
        d = float(d)
        return self.balance

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance()
```

This the class that is making the object

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def btnclicked(self):
        search_name = self.sender()
        if search_name.text() in namecheck:
            with open('C:/Users/rbell/PycharmProjects/SDEV140/Final_project/users.txt') as fhand:
                for line in fhand:
                    if search_name.text() in line:
                        line = line.rstrip('\n')
                        array = line.split(",")
                        stringtofloat = float(array[2])
                        x = BankAccount(array[0], array[1])
                        x.balance = stringtofloat
                        print(x.full_name,x.acctNum, x.balance)
            self.secwin.show()
        else:
            print('\nError\n')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.left = 440
        self.top = 260
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("");
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome to Reese's Bank!\nEnter account number:")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle("first window")
        self.show()
        self.lineedit.editingFinished.connect(self.btnclicked)
        self.secwin = secondwindow()
```

How do I take the x = BankAccount() data and use in another class like

```
class ViewBalance(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewBalance, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Your balance is: ")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("x.Balance")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
```

The self.label2 is where I would like to display the balance of the x BankAccount object. Do the order of the classes matter? The BankAccount class is at the top under the Imports, the ViewBalance class is under the BankAccount, and the Window Class is at the bottom.

This is the code in its entirety

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

with open('numlist.txt') as f:
     namecheck = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
search_name=999
w=0
d=0
sendto=''

class BankAccount():
    def __init__(self, name, acct):
        self.full_name = name
        self.acctNum = acct
        self.balance = 0

    def withdraw(self, w):
        self.balance = self.balance - w
        w = float(w)
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, d):
        self.balance = self.balance + d
        d = float(d)
        return self.balance

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance()

# def saveinfo():
#     accountname = str(x.full_name)
#     accountnumber= str(x.acctNum)
#     accountbalance= str(x.balance)
#     objectlist= [accountname + ', ' + accountnumber + ', ' + accountbalance]
#     savedata = (objectlist[0])
#     latestsave= savedata
#     with open('users.txt', 'r') as ds:
#         with open('tempuserlist.txt', 'w') as es:
#             for line in ds:
#                 if x.acctNum not in line:
#                     es.write(line)
#     with open('users.txt', 'r') as ds:
#         with open('lastuseredit.txt', 'w') as es:
#             if latestsave not in line:
#                 es.write('\n')
#                 es.write(savedata)
#     joinfiles=['tempuserlist.txt', 'lastuseredit.txt']
#     with open('users.txt', 'w') as output:
#         for thing in joinfiles:
#             with open(thing) as input:
#                 output.write(input.read())


class ViewBalance(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewBalance, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Your balance is: ")
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("x.Balance")
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

class DepositMoney(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DepositMoney, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("How much would you like to deposit? ");
        self.lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit();
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineedit1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

class WithdrawMoney(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WithdrawMoney, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("How much would you like to withdraw? ");
        self.lineedit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit();
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineedit1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

class secondwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def buttonclk(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        try:
            if sender.text() == "View Balance":
                self.vb.show()
            elif sender.text() == "Deposit":
                self.dm.show()
            elif sender.text() == "Withdraw":
                self.wm.show()
            elif sender.text() == "Save/Exit":
                exit()
        except ValueError:
            print("Try again")

    def __init__(self):
        super(secondwindow, self).__init__()
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.left = 440
        self.top = 260
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello x.Full_name");
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("View Balance");
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Deposit");
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Withdraw");
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Save/Exit");

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button2)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button3)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button4)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.buttonclk)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.buttonclk)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.buttonclk)
        self.button4.clicked.connect(self.buttonclk)

        self.vb = ViewBalance()
        self.dm = DepositMoney()
        self.wm = WithdrawMoney()

        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle("Second window")


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def btnclicked(self):
        search_name = self.sender()
        if search_name.text() in namecheck:
            with open('users.txt') as fhand:
                for line in fhand:
                    if search_name.text() in line:
                        line = line.rstrip('\n')
                        array = line.split(",")
                        stringtofloat = float(array[2])
                        x = BankAccount(array[0], array[1])
                        x.balance = stringtofloat
                        print(x)
                        print("it's here")
            self.secwin.show()
        else:
            print('\nError\n')


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.left = 440
        self.top = 260
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480

        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit();
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Press enter when ready!");
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome to Reese's Bank!\nEnter account number:")

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.lineedit.editingFinished.connect(self.btnclicked)
        self.secwin = secondwindow()

        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle("first window")
        self.show()



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    main.show
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code is reading from, and should write to, two different files to get the premade objects, like Reese, 000, 500.0.

Comment: Can't you pass the object as an initializer parameter?

Comment: @AliMomenSani How do I do that?

Comment: Are you creating `ViewBalance` instances inside `Window` class?

Comment: @AliMomenSani No I don't think so. What you see in the Window class is all that I wrote for it.

Comment: Send the `BankAccount` to `ViewBalance` like you do for `name` and `acct` for `BankAccount`.

Comment: I did that and now there are errors everywhere. Errors like "line 166, in main
    main = Window() TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'BankAccount'" and "line 166, in main
    main = Window(x) NameError: name 'x' is not defined"

Comment: @Reese_E. What is the line `self.secwin = secondwindow()` doing? And where do you use the `ViewBalance` class? Or is `secondwindow()` supposed to be `ViewBalance()`?

Comment: The secondwindow() is a Class that opens a main window which has a view balance button that open the ViewBalance() class

Answer (score 0):

You'll always have to know the name of the **instance** you are working with. 
Here's an example of a mechanism: I do not have PyQt5 installed and the code is not really minimal, but here's how you could set up the mechanism in your code. I have stripped all code not relating to the passing of objects.

Since I have no example data I'm simply assigning what seems to be ok...

```
class BankAccount():            # Keeps bank account balance
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 445

class ViewBalance(): # Prints variable x of instancewin of class Window
    def show(self, b):
        print('ViewBalance print b:', b)

class Window(): 
    def __init__(self):
        x = BankAccount()       # Creates instance x of class BankAccount
        print('Window print x.balance:', x.balance)
        self.vb = ViewBalance()
        self.vb.show(x.balance) # Call instance vb of class ViewBalance
                                # to show balance

win = Window()
```

Comment: Updated my example.